# Highlight link based on current page (Dynamic Navigation PHP)

Tags: php, html, css

This might be very easy for some but I've tried various ways to get it to work but to no avail.

Here's a brief;

I have one page, I have links in this page that when clicked load other pages but display them in the same page.

```
    <section class="posts-header">
    <div class="col span-3-of-3">
    <ul class="posts-nav" id="navigation">
    <li><a href="blog_admin_posts.php?source=view_all_posts">View Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog_admin_posts.php?source=view_posts">View Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog_admin_posts.php?source=add_posts">Create Post</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </section>
```

The above code shows links that when clicked, pass a variable using `$_GET` to the switch statement below;

```
if(isset($_GET['source'])) {
$source = $_GET['source'];}

switch($source) {
case 'view_posts';
    include "php/blog_posts_view.php";
    break;

case 'view_all_posts';
    include "php/blog_posts_reviewer.php";
    break;

case 'add_posts';
    include "php/blog_posts_addform.php";
    break;

case 'edit_posts';
    include "php/blog_posts_editform.php";
    break;

default:
    include "php/blog_posts_view.php";
    break;}
```

How can I highlight the current page? using html, js, css3 or all.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define an `active` class in CSS, which describes the style of an active link. For example, a very simple style:

```
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

Then you have to modify your menu:

```
<section class="posts-header">
    <div class="col span-3-of-3">
        <ul class="posts-nav" id="navigation">
            <li><a href="blog_admin_posts.php?source=view_all_posts"<?=$_GET['source'] == "view_all_posts" ? " class=\"active\"" : ""; ?>>View Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog_admin_posts.php?source=view_posts"<?=$_GET['source'] == "view_posts" ? " class=\"active\"" : ""; ?>>View Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog_admin_posts.php?source=add_posts"<?=$_GET['source'] == "add_posts" ? " class=\"active\"" : ""; ?>>Create Post</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

The active menu link text should now be displayed in red.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you will find this very helpful, it adds your class to the current page and allows to add more links to your page by simply adding to the array.

```
<?php
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page']:  ' ';
    $pages = ['view_all_posts','view_posts','add_posts'];
    $active = '';
    if (in_array($page,$pages)){
        $active = 'active';
    }
 ?>
```

Then modify your menu:

```
<section class="posts-header">
  <div class="col span-3-of-3">
    <ul class="posts-nav" id="navigation">
    <?php foreach ($pages as $key => $value) : ?>
      <li>
        <a href="blog_admin_posts.php?source=<?=$value?>" class="<?=$active?>"><?=$value?></a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page name using this:

```
$pageName = $_GET["source"];
```

And then, for every list item, you could do something like this:

```
<li class="<?= ($pageName === 'firstPageName') ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="...">...</a></li>
```

Of course, you'll need to style the class `.active` or how ever you would like to name it.

Comment: Problem with your solution is that the page name stays the same, I just echoed `$pageName`, circled through all the pages and I'm still getting the same page name

Comment: Ah I completely missed the fact it's all blog_admin_posts.php - A simple solution is to replace $pageName with $pageName = $_GET["source"] and work based on that. Edited my original answer to fit the fix.